# Erlang: how can I automatically start all necessary applications to app?

Tags: erlang

I have necessary applications in st_db.app file like this:

```
{application, st_db,
 [
  {description, ""},
  {vsn, "1.0.0"},
  {registered, []},
  {modules, [st_db_app, st_db_sup, st_db]},
  {applications, [
                  kernel,
                  stdlib,
          sasl,
          crypto,
          ibrowse,
          couchbeam
                 ]},
  {mod, { st_db_app, []}},
  {env, []}
 ]}.
```

I need to start them (crypto, sasl, etc.) automatically to run and debug the main app.
The only solution I found is to start erl with such params:

```
erl -pa ./ebin -pa ./deps/*/ebin -boot start_sasl -s couchbeam -s crypto -s ibrowse
```

Is that the only way?

PS: btw couchbeam doesn't starts on node. It just start the couchbeam's supervisor, so I have to run in shell it manually

```
=PROGRESS REPORT==== 15-Jun-2011::10:22:43 ===
          supervisor: {local,couchbeam_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.62.0>},
                       {name,couchbeam},
                       {mfargs,{couchbeam,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,permanent},
                       {shutdown,2000},
                       {child_type,worker}]

2> application:start(couchbeam).
ok
3> 
=PROGRESS REPORT==== 15-Jun-2011::10:23:25 ===
          supervisor: {local,couchbeam_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.69.0>},
                       {name,couchbeam},
                       {mfargs,{couchbeam,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,permanent},
                       {shutdown,2000},
                       {child_type,worker}]

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 15-Jun-2011::10:23:25 ===
         application: couchbeam
          started_at: nonode@nohost
```

Is there way to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either issue a series of `-eval "application:start(coucnbeam)"` commands to `erl`, or do it the proper OTP way and use `reltool` to generate a new boot file for you.

See [info](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/reltool.html) on reltool, also rebar does an excellent job at doing much of the heavy lifting for you so you might want to look into [rebar3](https://github.com/erlang/rebar3).

There is also a [great chapter](https://learnyousomeerlang.com/release-is-the-word), from LYSE, on making releases.

Answer (score 5):

If you are just messing around in the console and want to not have to type in all these 'application:start(...).' lines, just put these things in the .erlang file in your current working directory. Here's an example for what I'm working on right now:

```
$ cat .erlang 
application:start(crypto).
application:start(public_key).
application:start(ssl).
application:start(ibrowse).
application:start(foo).
```

This starts all my dependencies, and then the app I'm working on right now, foo.

---

If you want to generate a reltool release with rebar, this link might help:

[When to use erlang application:start or included_applications and a supervisor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141198/when-to-use-erlang-applicationstart-or-included-applications-and-a-supervisor)

Specifically, this gist:

https://gist.github.com/3728780

-Todd

Answer (score 2):

In your application callback module, just write:

```
-module(st_db_app).
-behaviour(application).
-export([start/2, stop/1]).

start(_StartType, _StartArg) ->
    %% Get application name
    {ok, AppName} = application:get_application(),
    %% Start all dependencies that are not yet started for application name
    {ok, _StartedApps} = application:ensure_all_started(AppName),
    %% start application's root supervisor or do other initialization here
    %% and return root supervisor's pid.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to start all dependent applications.
Please go through application:ensure_all_started API at http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#ensure_all_started-1